# Android Bootstrap mvn clean package error

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, android-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the android bootstrap : https://github.com/donnfelker/android-bootstrap

So I followed instructions :

- Generate app from website
- Install Maven (Windows 7 here)
- Add some environment var (JAVA_HOME, M2, M2_HOME, ANDROID_HOME)
- Check for Maven successfull installation (cmd > mvn --version)

Everything looks fine.

So i try the next command from the app directory :

```
mvn clean package
```

And I get some error during build :

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 41.770s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Oct 17 17:22:28 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/66M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:andr
oid-maven-plugin:3.3.0:proguard (default-proguard) on project com-jschmitt-diale
r: MojoExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = cmd.exe
 /X /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\java" -Xmx512M -jar "C:
\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\proguard\lib\proguard.jar" @../pr
oguard.cfg -injars C:\Users\Julien\Documents\Android\Bootstrap\app\target\classe
s -injars C:\Users\Julien\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.1\gson-2.1.
jar(!META-INF/maven/**,!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) -injars C:\Users\Julien\.m2\reposi
tory\com\github\rtyley\roboguice-sherlock\1.4\roboguice-sherlock-1.4.jar(!META-I
NF/maven/**,!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) -injars C:\Users\Julien\.m2\repository\org\ro
boguice\roboguice\2.0\roboguice-2.0.jar(!META-INF/maven/**,!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
) -injars C:\Users\Julien\.m2\repository\com\google\inject\guice\3.0\guice-3.0-n
o_aop.jar(!META-INF/maven/**,!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) -injars C:\Users\Julien\.m2\
repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar(!META-INF/maven/**,!ME
TA-INF/MANIFEST.MF) -injars C:\Users\Julien\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopallian
ce\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar(!META-INF/maven/**,!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) -injars C:\
Users\Julien\.m2\repository\com\google\android\support-v4\r7\support-v4-r7.jar(!
META-INF/maven/**,!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) -injars C:\Users\Julien\.m2\repository\
com\github\kevinsawicki\http-request\2.1\http-request-2.1.jar(!META-INF/maven/**
,!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) -injars C:\Users\Julien\.m2\repository\com\nineoldandroi
ds\library\2.2.0\library-2.2.0.jar(!META-INF/maven/**,!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) -in
jars C:\Users\Julien\.m2\repository\com\github\kevinsawicki\android-pusher\0.6\a
ndroid-pusher-0.6.jar(!META-INF/maven/**,!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) -libraryjars "C:
\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\rt.jar" -libraryjars "C:\Program F
iles (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\jsse.jar" -libraryjars "C:\Program Files (x8
6)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\jce.jar" -libraryjars C:\Users\Julien\.m2\repository
\com\google\android\android\4.1.1.4\android-4.1.1.4.jar(!org/xml/**,!org/w3c/**,
!org/apache/http/**,!java/**,!javax/**,!android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.class
) -libraryjars C:\Users\Julien\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.
1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar -libraryjars C:\Users\Julien\.m2\repository\org\ap
ache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.0.1\httpclient-4.0.1.jar -libraryjars C:\Users\
Julien\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.0.1\httpcore-4.0.1.ja
r -libraryjars C:\Users\Julien\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.3\co
mmons-codec-1.3.jar -libraryjars C:\Users\Julien\.m2\repository\org\khronos\open
gl-api\gl1.1-android-2.1_r1\opengl-api-gl1.1-android-2.1_r1.jar -libraryjars C:\
Users\Julien\.m2\repository\xerces\xmlParserAPIs\2.6.2\xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar -
libraryjars C:\Users\Julien\.m2\repository\xpp3\xpp3\1.1.4c\xpp3-1.1.4c.jar -lib
raryjars C:\Users\Julien\.m2\repository\org\json\json\20080701\json-20080701.jar
 -libraryjars C:\Users\Julien\.m2\repository\com\actionbarsherlock\library\4.1.0
\library-4.1.0.jar -outjars 'C:\Users\Julien\Documents\Android\Bootstrap\app\tar
get\proguard-obfuscated.jar' -dump 'C:\Users\Julien\Documents\Android\Bootstrap\
app\target\proguard\dump.txt' -printseeds 'C:\Users\Julien\Documents\Android\Boo
tstrap\app\target\proguard\seeds.txt' -printusage 'C:\Users\Julien\Documents\And
roid\Bootstrap\app\target\proguard\usage.txt' -printmapping 'C:\Users\Julien\Doc
uments\Android\Bootstrap\app\target\proguard\mapping.txt'", Result = 1 -> [Help
1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

As this is the first time I use Android Bootstrap and Maven I do not understand what kind of error this is and how to correct it...

If you need more informations such as the POM file or the detailled environment var do not hesitate to ask me !

Comment: You got solutions for that issues.Because i am facing the same problem

Comment: Just followed Richard' solution and now works great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your java bin path has spaces in it. Java/Proguard is too stupid to handle that.

Comment: Very usefull tip !
Will try it ASAP !